# Ember deprecation warning and str.replace error in simple app

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember and am trying to set up a fairly simple app. Fetch some data from the server and list it, but I keep running into a

```
"Usage of Ember.DeferredMixin or Ember.Deferred is deprecated."
```

warning and a

```
"TypeError: str.replace is not a function"
```

error, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Everything should be here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/303/

Could anyone please tell me what the heck I'd doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: what version of ember are you using? are you using ember-cli? If not you should have a look at ember-cli as this is the preffered way to use ember now. www.ember-cli.com      
via http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations/#toc_deprecations-added-in-1-7 - 

Ember.DeferredMixin and Ember.Deferred have been deprecated in favor of using RSVP.Promises.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Bower installed an ancient version of Ember-data, and I had to manually enter the newest (beta) version number in the bower.json file. Problem solved!